how to customise window.onbeforeunload in js
How to get over own custom message in website using window.onbeforeunload (on browser's closing tab)
I am trying to get customised own messageon when someone leaving my site
I wanna my own custom message like thanks for visit do you want to leave

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As I remember You cannot show custom popup,
but you can show popup to ask "changes you made may not be saved" by doing:
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = true;
});


